# Terminate mips program without using syscall 10 ( need to store something else in $v0 at the end)

Tags: mips, system-calls, terminate

Usually to exit from a mips program i need to call

```
syscall (10) in `$v0`
```

or  in general, we need to associate a value to `$v0`.

But what about if i want to print, exit ecc, preserving the actual value in `$v0` without changing it with the syscall code?

(so at the end of program $v0 must display the actual value )

Comment: You have to tell us what simulator you're using, because the details of exit conditions from `main` vary; for example, between QtSpim and MARS.  While both allow program exit via syscall 10, QtSpim (defaults to) invokes `main` as a function, which means main can return instead of syscall exit, though MARS doesn't so the "main" code in MARS has no where to return, but it allows running off the end.

Comment: @ErikEidt yes sorry ! i use mars and yes , i fixed that creating a "Bottom" jump at the end so programm will finish automatically and i can save my value in $v0, thanks anyway!